# how to differentiate user type on login in php?

Tags: php

here is the php code am trying ,it only works on one user and i dont know to use the user type code.

```
<?php
    class Admin{

            /// User Login
    public function AdminlogIn($user,$password)
    {   
        $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","animal"); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$user' AND password='$password'";
        $result =  $con->query($sql);
        $count = $result->num_rows > 0;
        $name = $result->fetch_row();
        echo "<script> alert(".$count.")</script>";

        if ($count==1)
        {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['username'] = $name[0];
             $_SESSION['password'] = $name[1];

             $role = $row['Role'];



             header("location:admin.php");




        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed to login" . "<br/> <br/>";
        }


    } 

}
?>
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection. A malicious user can bypass your login code.

Comment: What is *user type code*? Do you mean the Role? What do you want to do with this value? What do you mean by it only works on one user? Too many questions...

Comment: @user8718169 what is your table structure. can store the roles in table.

Comment: because you only count 1 user in your code. and where this come from ? `$row['Role']`?

Comment: the $row['Role'] i was trying to fetch the value that differentiate the admin and the user cause they are all in one table in the database

Answer (score 0):

Add user type in database table field or you can say that user role and check it when user attempt to login if user credentials found and type is admin redirect it to admin page or redirect to user dashboard else on login failed.

Comment: do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1.) First Add user type in database table field, Your database table structure like that:-

```
table:-
    id    username   password   Role 
    1      ---         ----     admin
    2       ---        ----     Student
    3       ----        ----    Teacher
```

I think your problem is checking the condition ,use if and else statements.

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $name[0];
  $_SESSION['password'] = $name[1];
  $_SESSION['Role'] = $name[2];


if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'admin'){
   header("Location: admin.php");
   }
else if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'Student'){
   header("Location: Student.php");
   }
else if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'Teacher'){
   header("Location: Teacher.php");
   }
else{
   echo "Your not logged in";
   }
```

Hope it Helps you....

Comment: okay i think  this might work .lemme try applying it to my code

Comment: @user8718169    Yes ,  it will absolutely work for u , as i understand your requirement. You will try & let me Know For further clarification.

Comment: i have tried the code but because on the first  if statement i declared the if($count==1), everytime i try to login its giving me an output of "1" with an okay button so when i press it it gives me a message of "your not logged in"

Comment: @user8718169  in alert box u get "1" means u store double quoted values for different users, like "1", "2"  not its name of users.